# Writing to pipes in python - Write time varying wildly for similar inputs

Tags: python, json, pipe, twisted

So, I write jsons to a pipe. Something like this:

```
os.write(pipe, json.dumps(response_json) + "\n")
```

I use "\n" because I do readline on the other side.

My jsons are pretty similar. I send a json dictionary and some values may be longer than other, for example an url field like

> www.example.com

vs

> www.example.com/something/something/something

However, the difference is not very big.

Some pipe writes take less than a second. Others, 30 seconds or more. Why could this happen?

For context, I am using twisted. The pipe write is a function called by the result of a deferred callback.

Something like this:

```
deferred = some_blocking_operation()
deferred.addCallback(some_function)

def some_function(result):
    write_to_pipe(result)
```

Why would write times be so varied?

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing what's reading from the pipe, it's impossible to answer this question. Please attach an http://sscce.org demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Glyph I kinda fixed this issue by moving the writing to a callback, since it's a blocking operation. I am now facing another issue. But it's beyond the scope of this question so I'll make another.